# Bypass Django to serve static files with Nginx

Tags: django, nginx

I'm trying to serve static files with Nginx, but it seems like Django takes control of the path and keeps giving a 404 because it's not a valid URL within the Django app.

Here's the Nginx server setup:

```
server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  localhost;

    client_max_body_size 500M;

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        root /app/interfaces/web/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass django;
        include /app/interfaces/web/django/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

I have tried all following combinations:

- `/static/` and `/static`
- With and without `autoindex on`
- `root` and `alias`

When I try to access a file in the /static/ directory, I get the following 404 error from Django:

> Page not found (404)
>
> Request Method:   GET Request
>
> URL:    https://172.16.6.158/static/test.css
>
> Using the URLconf defined in django.urls, Django tried these URL
>   patterns, in this order:
>
> ^ ^$ [name='index']
>
> ^history/
>
> ^config/
>
> ^admin/
>
> The current path, static/test.css, didn't match any of these.

I also tried to set `STATIC_URL` in Django settings, but I don't think that should be neccessary since I'm trying to bypass Django. And it didn't make any difference anyway.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Do I need to change configuration somewhere else.

**UPDATE**

The Nginx access log gives the following error:

> 172.16.6.108 - - [11/Dec/2017:11:53:11 +0000] "GET /static/test.css HTTP/1.1" 404 3132 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100
>   Safari/537.36" "-"

There's nothing in the error log.

Used setup:

```
location /static/ {
    alias /app/interfaces/web/static;
}
```

Comment: First of all if you have path with `/static` inside then you need to use `alias` directive and not root. Next you should tell what you see in Nginx access and error logs. Also you don't need the `autoindex on;` thing

Comment: I updated the question with result from access log

Comment: Are you sure that there is no other nginx configuration that is having some conflicts? Because `server_name` is localhost but you are using an IP on that, so I am not sure that it is correct. To be sure, add logging parameters to different files to be sure that you are seeing the configuration that is being triggered.

Comment: You're right. Turned out that it was the wrong configuration file I tested with. ´location /static {
    alias /app/interfaces/web/static;
}´ works. Feel a little embarassed...

Answer (score 2):

put this code inside server block

```
# Django media location 
 location  /media { alias /home/username/djangoproject/media; }

 location /static { alias /home/username/djangoproject/app/static;}
 # your Django project's static files `
```

and also you need to add static url and media url to urlpattern .google for serving static file in django